# Does $\text{rank}(AB)= \text{rank}(BA)= \text{rank}(A)$ imply that B is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

(After revision) I would like to prove that if $A$ and $B$ are nonzero, $\text{rank}(AB)= \text{rank}(BA)= \text{rank}(A)$ imply that B is invertible, but don’t know where to start the proof. Any help or hints?

Comment: @Coco The converse fails with (counter)examples as straightforward as $A＝B＝\displaystyle\sum_{i＝1}^k\mathrm{E}_{ii}$, for $k<n$ (where $\mathrm{E}_{kl}$ are the traditional elementary matrices). This holds more generally over any field.

Comment: @projectilemotion yeah I know it. How does it help in this proof?

Comment: @Coco A statement which is indeed true is the following: let $K$ be an arbitrary field, $V$ an arbitrary left $K$-vector space and $f \in \mathrm{End}_{\operatorname{K-\mathbf{Mod}}}(V)$ an endomorphism of $V$ such that $\mathrm{rk}(f \circ g)＝\mathrm{rk}g$ for *any* endomorphism $g$ of $V$. Then $f \in \mathrm{GL}_K(V)$ is an automorphism.

Comment: Make that a *finite dimensional* $V$ in my previous comment. In order to have a valid claim in the general case one would require the two-sided hypothesis $\mathrm{rk}(g \circ f)＝\mathrm{rk}(f \circ g)＝\mathrm{rk}g$ for any endomorphism $g$.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ thanx, I haven’t learned these stuff, but you are correct, mine is false. May I wonder are what you mentioned knowledge of abstract algebra?

Comment: It is knowledge of the general theory of vector spaces (arbitrary dimensions, over arbitrary - not necessarily commutative - fields).

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\rank{rank}$The equivalence you might be looking for is:

> An $n\times n$ matrix $B$ is invertible if and only if $\rank(AB)=\rank(BA)=\rank(A)$ holds **for all** $n\times n$ matrices $A$.

The proof of the first direction was your original homework question:

> If $B$ is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix then $\rank(AB)=\rank(BA)=\rank(A)$ holds for all $n\times n$ matrices $A$.

The other direction is:

> If $B$ is an $n\times n$ matrix such that $\rank(AB)=\rank(BA)=\rank(A)$ holds **for all** $n\times n$ matrices $A$, then $B$ is invertible.

To prove this, note that since the equation holds **for all** $A$ by assumption, it also holds for $A=I$ (the identity matrix), which yields
$$
\rank(B) = \rank(I) = n.
$$
Hence $B$ is of full rank and invertible.

---

However, in your question you proposed the following statement

> If $A$ and $B$ are non-zero $n\times n$ matrices and $\rank(AB)=\rank(BA)=\rank(A)$ holds, then $B$ is invertible.

This statement is **false** as shown by the counter example in morphy22's answer.

One counter example is enough to show that this statement is false in general and hence it is impossible to prove it.

Comment: Thank you so much! It’s very detailed. Yes, it only holds for nonzero A,B, I’ll revise my question.

Comment: No, as @morphy22 showed, it (your proposed statement) doesn't even hold for non-zero $A,B$.

Comment: oh yes, I mean adding $A,B$ nonzero as an prerequisite.

Comment: Yes, it is still false.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand the slight difference between for all and not.

Answer (score 7):

I have a counterexample.
Try :
$$A=B= \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you. I think it’s a good counterexample, but I don’t think it proves formally.

Comment: I thought @Coco wants to prove or disprove that $rank(AB) = rank(BA) = rank(A)$ implies $B$ is invertible. Above is a counterexample.

Comment: @Coco You need a formal proof if you want to prove that a statement always holds. If you want to prove that a statement *does not* always hold, then there is no proof more formal or rigorous than a counterexample.

Comment: @morphy22 I'm sorry, I misread the question and thought that the OP wanted to prove the homework question instead. (+1)

Comment: It holds sometimes. Say $A = B =I$. I don't get what you mean by does not always hold. What you want to prove/disprove is to show that it holds always. The opposite of that is to show at least one case where it does not.

Comment: @BenGrossmann thank you, I think I didn’t state clearly enough. Do you know how to prove that it always hold?

Comment: @Coco It is impossible to prove a false statement

Comment: @morphy22 Thank you, a nice counterexample, $AB=BA=A=B$, it seems there are many counterexamples like this.